# TypeError: v2.UpdataData is not a function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

> I am new to Angular and MVC , and I have created a code for display
>   records into table view.
>
> User can edit and delete that records by clicking the Edit and Delete
>   Link
>
> but it shows me error when i click on edit link **TypeError:
>   v2.UpdataData is not a function**
>
> and it also shows me error **TypeError: $http.get is not a function**
>   when i click on Delete Link
>
> Can anyone help me to solve this out. Thanks in advance.

**Controller.js**

```
    //update data of table
        $scope.UpdataData = [];
        //UpdateData();
        $scope.UpdateData = function (StateMaster) {
            var RetValData = DataService.UpdateStudent(StateMaster);
            debugger;
            getData.then(function (StateMaster) {
                debugger;
                StateID: $scope.StateID;
                StateName: $scope.StateName;
                CountryName: $scope.CountryName;
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in getting records');
            });
    }
 $scope.DeleteData = [];
    $scope.DeleteData = function (r, index) {
        var retval = DataService.DeleteData(r.StateID).success(function (msg) {
            $scope.countrydata.splice(index, 1);
             alert('Student has been deleted successfully.');  
        }).error(function () {
            alert('Oops! something went wrong.');
        });
    }.factory('DataService', function ($http) {
    var fac={}
    debugger;
    fac.UpdateData= function($http)
    {
        return $http.get('/State/UpdateData');
    }
    return fac;
}).factory('DataService', function () {
    var fac={}
    debugger;
    fac.DeleteData = function ($http)
    {
        return $http.get('/State/DeleteData');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

**StateController.cs**

```
    public string UpdateData(StateMaster r)
            {
                if (r != null)
                {
                    using (simpleEntities dbContext = new simpleEntities())
                    {
                        StateMaster lstdata = dbContext.StateMasters.Where(x => x.StateID == r.StateID).FirstOrDefault();
                        lstdata.StateName = r.StateName;
                        lstdata.CountryName = r.CountryName;
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
                        return "Data Updated";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "something went worng";
                }
            }
[HttpPost]
        public string DeleteData(int id)
        {
            if (id != 0)
            {
                using (simpleEntities databContext = new simpleEntities())
                {
                    var lsdata = databContext.StateMasters.Where(x => x.StateID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    databContext.StateMasters.Remove(lsdata);
                    databContext.SaveChanges();
                    return "Data Deleted Successfully";
                }
            }
            else {
                return "Error Occured";
            }
        }
```

**InsertState.cshtml**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="StateController">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>Sr. No.</td>
                <td>Country Name</td>
                <td>State Name</td>
                <td></td>
                @*<td>Country Name</td>*@
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in countrydata">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{r.CountryName}}</td>
                <td>{{r.StateName}}</td>
                @*<td>{{r.CountryName}}</td>*@
                <td>
                    <span ng-click="UpdataData(r)" class="btnAdd">Edit</span> |
                    <span ng-click="DeleteData(r)" class="btnRed">Delete</span>
                </td>  
            </tr>



        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is code of dataservice ???

Comment: see in controller.js @PranayRana , i just attached my service code

Comment: this is compiletime error or runtime ??

Comment: runtime @PranayRana

Comment: can you plase try the way i suggested ...first try simple and then go for big one ...i.e. fist just try to call factory method if it works than you put you http code in that to call serverside function

Comment: i just only have issue to update my records. However adding records and displaying them into table view(and their factory) working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

there is problem in you code with this

`line  $scope.UpdateData = function (StateMaster`

as you are trying to run fuction of your $scop but fuction is of factory so you have to try like

```
factory.UpdateDate
```

---

Seem like there is problem in defining `factory` in angular , you can try below way

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.factory('testFactory', function(){
        return {
            sayHello: function(text){
                return "Factory says \"Hello " + text + "\"";
            },
            sayGoodbye: function(text){
                return "Factory says \"Goodbye " + text + "\"";
            }  
        }               
    });

   function HelloCtrl($scope, testService, testFactory)
   {
      $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.sayHello("World");
   }
```

you can place your function and just try out it return you value or not

Comment: there is no problem in defining factory in angular because i have already created 3-4 factory in a same document and it all works nicely @PranayRana

Comment: @DheerajSharma - i found issue see my updated answer ...you have to make call to factory function which is factory.udpatedata as $scope not having function updatedata you are getting error

Comment: i did the changes as you said but, unfortunately it shows me the error "ReferenceError: factory is not defined"  and no data showing in my table view now @PranayRana

Comment: @DheerajSharma - you are trying too many things one go ...i suggest go step by step and fist define factory as i suggested and than try to make use of that factory in your controller and than go for big change